# SQL Server Function not producing expected output

Tags: sql-server

I have written below function in SQL Server:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnFormatMessage 
    (@Message varchar(max), @Thought varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FinalMessage AS varchar(max) = ' '

    SELECT
        @FinalMessage = LTRIM(RTRIM(CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ISNULL(@Thought,''))))) > 0 THEN
                                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,'')), LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,''))) , 1) IN ('?','!', '.')THEN
                                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,''))
                                ELSE 
                                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,''))
                                END
                            + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +'My Thoughts: ' + CHAR(13) 
                            + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Thought,'')), LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Thought,''))) , 1) IN ('?','!', '.') THEN
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Thought,''))
                            ELSE 
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Thought,'')) + '.'
                            END
                    ELSE
                        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,'')), LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,''))) , 1) IN ('?','!', '.') OR 
                                                                                                                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,'')) = ''
                        THEN
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,''))
                        ELSE 
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@Message,'')) + '.'
                        END 
                END)) 
                Return @FinalMessage
    END
```

When I run it as

```
 Select dbo.fnFormatMessage('This is a message', 'This is my thought')
```

I am expecting below output:

```
This is a message
My Thought: This is my thought
```

But it just returns T

Comment: `RETURNS VARCHAR` should be `RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)`. Thank you, that'll be $1000 in consulting fees. :-)

Comment: Break it down into smaller pieces and find the bug. You can do this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks ;)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `RETURNS varchar` to `RETURNS varchar(8000)` or the appropriate length. Always use en explicit length to `VARCHAR`